# Woocommerce without wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am building an online store with wordpress+wocommerce. What I want to do is , once I am done with the all customization and publish the site, I no longer need the word press tools. The owner of the site is only interested in the data presented by wocommerce such as daily sales, visits etc. But the wordpress administration page is complex and complicated. So the question is, is it possible to remove all other stuff and just keep wocommerce for the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WooCommerce is a Wordpress plugin, so no, you can't run it without Wordpress. If your goal is to make the backoffice simple to your client, you can strip all the unnecessary menu items from the sidebar, so he only sees the WooCommerce options. Take a look at [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page) reference.

For example, to remove the Plugins item, in the theme's functions.php add:

```
add_action("admin_menu", "remove_items");
function remove_items() {
    remove_menu_page("plugins.php");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, probably this should also work, as long as I will be able to provide a simple back end focused on site data only.

Comment: Yeah, with that hook you can pretty much fully customize the admin panel sidebar.